# how to monitor java application (keycloak) with zabbix

Tags: java, keycloak, zabbix

I have an issue with monitoring java application (keycloak software) with zabbix 5.0. I found an article https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring how to do it. I need to add something like this to launch java app:

```
java \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-jar /usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-jre-headless/demo/jfc/Notepad/Notepad.jar
```

When i add neccessary strings to standalone.sh file in Then section, application is launched, but zabbix doesn't monitor an application by JMX interface.

When i add nessessary strings in Else section, application doesn't launch. It gives error.

Where should i write strings to monitor java application?

```
if [ "x$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" = "x" ]; then
      # Execute the JVM in the foreground
      eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Standalone]\" $JAVA_OPTS \
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 \
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
        -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
        \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"/server.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:"$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR"/logging.properties\" \
        -jar \""$JBOSS_HOME"/jboss-modules.jar\" \
         $MODULE_OPTS \
         -mp \""${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}"\" \
         org.jboss.as.standalone \
         -Djboss.home.dir=\""$JBOSS_HOME"\" \
         -Djboss.server.base.dir=\""$JBOSS_BASE_DIR"\" \
         "$SERVER_OPTS"
      JBOSS_STATUS=$?
   else
      # Execute the JVM in the background
      eval \"$JAVA\" -D\"[Standalone]\" $JAVA_OPTS \
        \"-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"/server.log\" \
         \"-Dlogging.configuration=file:"$JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR"/logging.properties\" \
         -jar \""$JBOSS_HOME"/jboss-modules.jar\" \
         $MODULE_OPTS \
         -mp \""${JBOSS_MODULEPATH}"\" \
         org.jboss.as.standalone \
         -Djboss.home.dir=\""$JBOSS_HOME"\" \
         -Djboss.server.base.dir=\""$JBOSS_BASE_DIR"\" \
         "$SERVER_OPTS" "&"
      JBOSS_PID=$!
```

Comment: Is Zabbix also running on the same computer?

Comment: No, zabbix server runs on the another server

Comment: Then have you added `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname` option too (based on the documentation)?

Comment: no, i didn't add. It seems problem not in it.
When i add necessary strings, i have errors with LogManager in logs:

WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
 java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0079: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYLOG0078: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

Comment: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYLOG0078: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

Comment: it seems that Java doesn't see strings for log config in file after i add my strings